# Redux-react connect function does not work for root component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am using a middleware to restore Redux store from indexeddb. I want to use that data in the root component for routing, to check if user is connected. But it seems that the `connect` function does not connect the root component `state` to Redux.

When I was debugging I saw `mapStateToProps` never actually runs. This is the relevant part of index.js:

```
class AppProvider extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    persistStore(store, {storage: localforage}) // Populates the store from indexedDB
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}> // Here I need the user from redux
          <Route path="/login" render={() => (
          this.state.user ? ( <Redirect to="/dashboard"/> ) : ( <LoginPage/> )
        )}/>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps (state, ownProps) {
  return {
    user: state.user // function never runs!
  }
}

withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {})(AppProvider))

render(
  <AppProvider/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

---

UPDATE:
When trying this:

```
const Root = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {})(AppProvider))

render(
  <Root/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Comment: try importing from 'react-router-dom' and not 'react-router'

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the connected component.

Neither `withRouter` nor `connect` modify the original component.  They simply return a new component.

Try this;

```
const AppProviderWithRedux = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {})(AppProvider))

render(
  <AppProviderWithRedux/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: for some reason it breaks the routing and gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined`